# How may I return a const reference to an object from a method?

Tags: c#, constants, return-value

```cs
public Item getItem(ulong itemId)
{
    Item item = items[itemId]
    return item;
}
```

Now the problem is: the callee of `getItem` must be able to retrieve information that `item` holds; but not modify it.

Sorry, but I know C++ better than C#... I'm afraid I must fall back to C++ for a teeny tiny while just to make myself clear what I'm trying to achieve... So this is what I'd do in C++ in this situation:

```cpp
const Item& getItem(unsigned long itemId)
{
    const Item& item = items[itemId];
    return item;
}
```

Very well - now whoever called `getItem` may call getters on `item`, but not setters.

I need to achieve a similar result in C#... is it possible?

Comment: It depends if `Item` is a `class` or a `struct`.

Comment: While you might be able to hack something together, C# isn't usually used that way. Is there anything stopping you changing `Item` to make the properties read only?

Comment: If you need that, you should probably use a new object without the setters, like `ReadOnlyItem` that wraps the `Item` without the setters.

Comment: @RonBeyer or return an interface that Item implements, that only exposes getters

Comment: For completeness (just in case it's not already clear): C# has no notion of C++'s "const correctness" (nor do most other languages, for that matter). There's some support for immutability with structs, but since immutability is not the *purpose* of structs (and there are other consequences of using them) that's not a usual approach. If your code base has a real need to block callers from doing a bad thing, a wrapper interface or class is the way to go, as others have mentioned, but in many cases where C++ would use `const`, C# code bases would just go "don't do that, then".

Comment: Can you please give a simplified example of `Item`.

Comment: @ja72 Chess. `Item` is the current state of the board. The idea is that a player whose turn it currently is may make a move (modifying the state). The other player, and also possible spectators, must be able to see the board; but not make moves.

Comment: Are the players and the spectators just other objects that you too wrote the code for, or are they third-party, living in possibly hostile libraries? Only the latter case is something that would warrant protecting against. It's a good example of where C++ would use `const` as a matter of course, and in C# a read-only wrapper would usually be unnecessary work. (If the code was possibly *actively hostile*, as in a security risk, even in C++ this would not suffice, as you can `const_cast` the protection away. You would actually have to copy data.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert I am aware that `const` is a no security measure. My concerns are here purely aesthetics; I'm returing the board state to my own code that will serialize it to JSON and send that JSON to clients. I find it not very "clean" if this code will be capable of issuing move commands. Though, if this is not how things are done in C# and if C# developers would simply say "then don't call the `makeMove` method in the networking code then OK, I accept that and thank you for enlightening me. :)

Comment: Yes, for pure aesthetics C# programmers would not usually break out anything to guarantee immutability -- anyone modifying the board in serialization code could not possibly be doing so by mistake, so it's not a mistake worth guarding against. That's not to say immutability in C# isn't a very interesting topic that [luminaries have written about](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability/), though, and you could have a completely immutable chess board as well, which would preclude the mistake *and* do nice things for threading. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use interfaces to surface only getters while still supporting setters in the class that implements the interface. As long as you return the *interface*, any consumer will be restricted to only the getters that interface defines.

```
public interface IItem {
    string SomeProperty { get; }
}

public class Item : IItem {
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class ItemHandler {
    private Item _item = new Item();

    public IItem getItem() {
        _item.SomeProperty = "A Value";
        return _item;
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var itemHandler = new ItemHandler();
        var item = itemHandler.getItem();

        // You can read the property
        Console.WriteLine(item.SomeProperty);

        // You can't write to the property
        //item.SomeProperty = "A New Value";
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow - VERY COOL!!!!

Comment: Of course, the client can always cast into the original object and access the setter. `( item as Item).SomeProperty = "Cheating";` is perfectly legal and won't throw an error. I think the _OP_ needs enforced immutability by design.

Comment: Generally, you only do something like this to protect devs from _accidently_ stepping on data. To make it truly immutable things get a lot more complex. The comes down to if you're trying to guide the developer or enforce constraints.